# Как получить ссылки на профили пользователя в других социальных сетях из Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

На сколько мне известно, Facebook позволяет в информации о профиле указывать ссылки на профили пользователя в других социальных сетях (ВК, Twitter, Instagram). Можно ли эти данные получить с помощью Graph API? Сам долго искал, но найти не получилось.

Comment: Тоже искал в свое время, но так и нашел. Наверное нельзя получить, [в описании АПИ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) нет ничего похожего. У вас были или есть сдвиги, или тоже оставили затею